# How to extract with name with Regex in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a user name (x) from a string that looks like this:
"Request is from User 'x' using the 'y' app ..."

I would like to extract x.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
SELECT *,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(message,r"(?<=User ')[^']*") AS user_id
FROM `dataset...`
```

But I got an error from BigQuery:

> Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group rather than a positive lookbehind:

```sql
SELECT *,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(message, r"User '([^']*)") AS user_id
FROM `dataset...`
```

Here,

- `User '` - matches a `User '` string
- `([^']*)` - captures zero or more chars other than `'` into Group 1 that is returned by the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT("Request is from User 'fvaksman' using the 'y' app ...", r"[User\s'](\w+)[']")
```